# How do I position a flex container to be vertically and horizontally aligned while maintaining a footer?

Tags: html, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to vertically and horizontally center a sentence in one flex container while maintaining on the screen a footer. How can I accomplish this?

```
  <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 p-3 bg-primary">
    <div class="p-3 bg-info flex-grow-1">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="bg-danger p-3">center me - horizontally and vertically</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="p-3 bg-danger">
      footer
    </div>
  </div>
```

See example here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLjvKY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this styling to `bg-info` class

```css
.bg-info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

(you can also change the `flex-direction` to `column`, it works both way because there is just one element there)

Comment: I need a footer *and* centered content.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little confuse, Are you saying that you want your footer to stay the same and just the content get centered? or both of them get centered?
what I answered looks like this: [codepen](https://codepen.io/KimiaBashiran/pen/aawMbq)

Comment: Awesome bashiran! Thx.

Comment: you're welcome, happy to help! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.